# What is the scaling algorithm of the FFmpeg scale filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have upscaled and downscaled an image with following command.

`ffmpeg -s:v 1280:720 -r 25 -i input.yuv -vf scale=1920x1080 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv`

I'm wondering what kind of scaling algorithm is used to do down scaling (bilinear, bicubic,...)?

and how can I change the filter or add it if there is no filter in this command?

Answer (score 8):

## It depends on your FFmpeg version

If using FFmpeg > 4.4, or a build from the git master branch as of  commit [lavfi/vf_scale: use default swscale flags for scaler](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/9f14396a5103ec80893db801035ece5d14c0d3c5), then the default scaling algorithm is **bicubic**.

### If using FFmpeg 4.4 or older

- When using `-vf` the default scaling algorithm is **bicubic**.
- When using `-filter_complex` the default scaling algorithm is **bilinear**.

You can choose the algorithm with the `flags` option:

```
-vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos
```

You can see a list of algorithms with:

```
ffmpeg -h filter=scale
```

They will be listed under the `-sws_flags` option which shows **bicubic** as the default.

Comment: I did some checking and it's not so much that the default are different but that filter_complex initialization does not look at sws_flags. Will study the code and see if I can patch it.

Comment: @Mulvya Ah, ok. Looking forward to the patch.

Comment: @Gyan Did you have a chance to look at this?

Comment: Yeah, a few months ago. he default flags for swscale or swresample aren't applied to filter_complex. I should ask the committer why not.

Comment: Now -filter_complex's default is also bicubic. See: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/9f14396a5103ec80893db801035ece5d14c0d3c5